# How to convert this SQL into Hibernate function by creating Criteria?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How to convert this into Hibernate function by creating Criteria?

```
SELECT 
    id,
     AVG(CASE
        WHEN the_date BETWEEN  '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30'
                AND the_type = 'XYZ'   THEN occupancy
    END) AS XYZ_occupancy_avg_current_month
```

Comment: May we see what you have tried first? Please do not make asking a question your first port of call before a genuine attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Entity.class);
.setProjection(Projections.property("id"))
.setProjection(Projections.avg("CASE WHEN the_date BETWEEN  '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30'
                AND the_type = 'XYZ'   THEN occupancy
                END")) ;     
.list();
```